# One delegate with 2 methods

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, delegates

I have a WinForms application, some game.

When the user set his settings (Color and Shape, board size) I send those preferences by a delegate to the `GameForm`.

I need to enable the user to change his preferences also in the middle of the game,
so I have a button that opens a new form and the user can select the color and the shape.
But this method have less parameters than the first one. 
My question is how to use the same delegate to take 2 methods with different amount of 
parameters?

Comment: That's impossible, by definition.  This is the fundamental difference between delegates and function pointers, delegates are type safe in that they specify the signature of the method that can be assigned to it and how it can be invoked.

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: You keep using that word... I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: It can't be done. Pass it some default values or use a second delegate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771653/delegate-for-any-method-type-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delegate is *basically* the same as a multi-cast single-signature interface. If you need multiple methods, use an interface instead of a delegate.